# NULL::character varying CakePHP 3 Form

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I get **NULL::character varying** as the value of a Form in CakePHP 3 when I expect it to be blank as I just created new entity.
The controller code I use is

```
public function add() {
    $audience = $this->Audiences->newEntity();
    $this->set(compact('audience', 'languages'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['audience']);
```

In the add.ctp my code to redner the form is

```
echo $this->Form->create($audience, ['novalidate' => true]);
echo $this->Form->input('audience', ['type' => 'text']);
```

Comment: what do you mean by NULL character ? can you please explain.

Comment: @ManoharKhadka the message is in bold. so you should refer to NULL::character varying it's as I use Postgres.